# Could not find C:\Users\xerxe\Desktop\bioclin\compose\local\django:

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

After I run this in the terminal:

```
docker-compose -f local.yml build
```

I get this error:

```
could not find C:\Users\xerxe\Desktop\bioclin\compose\local\django: CreateFile C:\Users\xerxe\Desktop\bioclin\compose\local\django: The specified path could not be found.
```

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN groupadd -r django \
    && useradd -r -g django django

# Requirements have to be pulled and installed here, otherwise caching won't work
COPY ./requirements /requirements
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /requirements/production.txt \
    && rm -rf /requirements

COPY ./compose/production/django/gunicorn.sh /gunicorn.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /gunicorn.sh
RUN chmod +x /gunicorn.sh
RUN chown django /gunicorn.sh

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
RUN chown django /entrypoint.sh

COPY ./compose/production/django/celery/worker/start.sh /start-celeryworker.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celeryworker.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker.sh

COPY ./compose/production/django/celery/beat/start.sh /start-celerybeat.sh
RUN sed -i 's/\r//' /start-celerybeat.sh
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat.sh

COPY . /app

RUN chown -R django /app

USER django

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

> Blockquote

[image]

I really don't know why I'm getting this error, I guess it's an easy problem I don't really get it, if you need more detail pls ask.

Comment: You don't have a `compose/local` directory, is there something in your compose file `local.yml` referencing that directory?

Comment: I found this =>services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=gSkPQlpnyczDleJp
      - USE_DOCKER=yes
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start.sh

Comment: That dockerfile `./compose/local/django/Dockerfile` doesn't exist, did you mean to have a `compose/local` directory?

Comment: @IainShelvington thx I've fixed the problem changing with the right path